# How do I know if car ECU has a REV Limiter?

Tags: rpm, rev-limiter

My car is fairly new and not that well documented online (it's a new model from late 2015)

For safety, how do I know if my car has a REV-limiter without testing it and letting it go up the red line RPMs? Is there a visible hardware or a sticker somewhere that would denote this?

Comment: Research? Every car is going to be different.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase the question Paulster.

Comment: Cars from the 90s had fuel cutoff so it's safe to assume that all cars from that point on have fuel cutoff. Honestly though unless it's documented somewhere you'd have to dump the ECU ROM and decode it.

Comment: @Ben so is it safe to assume that all cars from 90s and onwards have REV Limiters?

Comment: @JomarSevillejo Yes I'd even assume  any fuel injected car has fuel cutoff.

Comment: @JomarSevillejo - As stated in my comment below ... It is a *very bad assumption* to believe all fuel injected cars have a rev limiter in them.

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 you mean there are modern fuel injected cars without rev limiters? I would find that hard to believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rev limiter is a bit of a misnomer since maximum engine RPM is a function of airflow. However there are such things as fuel and spark cut off which will disable either injectors or coil packs as a result of going over a predefined RPM (this also happens on deceleration).

Doing a little research I found a patent that dates back to 1980 (https://www.google.com/patents/US4336778).

So all in all it's safe to assume that any fuel injected engine has some kind of "rev limiter".

Comment: I really think it's a poor assumption and one I'd not believe is there. The only engine I *know for sure* has a limiter (or fuel/spark cutout) is the MX5 Miata. That's only because I tacked one up there once. There may be something in the PCM which does this automatically, but it's bad to assume this is there *in all fuel injected vehicles*. Plus, the link you provided is for fuel cutoff to save catalytic converters in the case of misfire, not to prevent over revving.

Comment: @paulster2 Pretty sure all OBD2 GMs have fuel cutoff (2000 + for sure). I know Mitsubishi uses one as well as Subaru. Nissan for sure as early as 89.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, but for the most part it's still an assumption. Is there a way *to know for sure* any engine has a fuel/spark cutoff? Without specifically researching any engine/vehicle you really don't know for sure. You'll want to double check the patent you have posted ... it's not for over revving, as I stated before.

Comment: @paulster2 you're right there's no way you would know without researching or testing yourself.

Comment: @ben Could it be possible for him to sue you if he blows his engine up?

Comment: I know my '87 944 has one, I've hit it a few times. Frankly, I'd be shocked if modern ECUs didn't have a simple ignition interrupt. I mean, they control the timing already, how hard would it be to tack on a map of "RPM > 7000 ? Timing = 30&deg; BTDC"?

Comment: @TMN - There would be three ways to know: 1) Bounce off the rev limiter; 2) Dissect the ECU code; 3) Do research on each and every vehicle. Other than that you are making an assumption, which in my opinion is a bad assumption. Mind you, I'm not necessarily disagreeing with your or Ben. It *makes sense that it would be there in modern FI setups* and be easy to implement ... but can we make a blanket statement which says it's absolutely there on each and every car ... the answer to that is an unequivocal ***No***.

Comment: i dont think the question is being answered: "how do I know if my car has a REV-limiter without testing it". is it possible to check without testing? in a limited number of cases you could call the dealer/manufacturer. otherwise, no, you have to test something. maybe the question should be revised?

Comment: @HandyHowie He's welcome to try if he does. I'm not a lawyer, but I doubt, "A guy on the internet told be it'd be safe" would stand up in small claims  court.

Comment: @DavidWinslow The question and my answer need revision. I've been thinking about it.